# How to automatically save emails to ascii files?

Tags: email, outlook, archive

I have a data stream that will be sent as daily emails containing temperature and wind speed from a measurement site. I would like to to automatically filter out these emails from the other emails I receive, then save the email body content to its own text file. Each text file must have a distinct file name; for example it could include the time that the email was sent or received. All files must all end up in a chosen directory. And ideally the process would be robust enough that it could run unattended for weeks. Our email system is Outlook but I could choose to send the email to my gmail account, for example. What is the big picture of how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bigger picture:** create a VBA script that runs on the `Items_ItemAdd` event, which fires whenever an email arrives.

**Specifics:** Use the solution on [this page](http://www.vboffice.net/sample.html?mnu=2&lang=en&smp=7&cmd=showitem), but in the Items_ItemAdd routine change the olSaveAsMsg to olSaveAsTxt to get the text format you want.
Note that the file name format in the example should match what you need, but you'll need to add criteria to the Items_ItemAdd routine to check that the message is one that you want to save.  For example, you could read the `Item.Subject` property.

Comment: Thanks, sounds perfect. Now off to learn about VBA and Outlook!

Comment: Great - have fun! There's a ton of good tutorials out there, as well as Microsoft's usual dry [intro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814736.aspx), and you might want to chase down the resources in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032409/good-tutorial-for-outlook-vba-programming).  Feel free to come back with any more questions of course!

Answer (score 0):

it means you are working with exchange, i suggest to use imap protocol to read the mails, and you will be able to save the body.